# Predict partition number for Postgres hash partitioning

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-13

I'm writting an app which uses partitions in Postgres DB. This is will be send to customers and run on their server. This implies that I have to be prepared for many different scenarios.
Lets start with simple table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dir (
   id SERIAL,
   volume_id BIGINT,
   path TEXT
);
```

I want to partition that table by volume_id column.

What I would like to achieve:

- limited number of partitions (right now it's 500 but I'm will be tweaking this parameter later)
- Do not create all partitions at once - add them only when they are needed
- support volume ids up to 100K
- [NICE TO HAVE] - been able for human to calculate partition number from volume_id

Solution that I have right now:

- partition by LIST
- each partition handles `volume_id % 500` like this:
  `CREATE TABLE dir_part_1 PARTITION OF dir FOR VALUES IN (1, 501, 1001, 1501, ..., 9501);`

This works great because I can create partition when it's needed, and I know exactly to which partition given volume_id belongs. But I have to manually declare numbers and I cannot support high volume_ids because speed of insert statements decrease drastically (more than 2 times).

It looks like I could try HASH partitioning but my biggest concern is that I have to create all partitions at the very beginning and I would like to be able to create them dynamically when they are needed, because planning time increases significantly up to 5 seconds for 500 partitions. For example I know that I will be adding rows with `volume_id=5`. How can I tell which partition should I create?

Comment: Definitely! Qeries for given volume_id are much faster, statistics per partition, independent autovacuum for each partition and all the others. I just don't want to pay cost of having unnecessary, unused partitions when I don't need them.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to force Postgres to use dummy hash function by adding hash operator for partitioned table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partition_custom_bigint_hash(value BIGINT, seed BIGINT)
RETURNS BIGINT AS $$
    -- this number is UINT64CONST(0x49a0f4dd15e5a8e3) from
    -- https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_STABLE/src/include/common/hashfn.h#L83
    SELECT value - 5305509591434766563;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE;


CREATE OPERATOR CLASS partition_custom_bigint_hash_op
    FOR TYPE int8
    USING hash AS
    OPERATOR 1 =,
    FUNCTION 2 partition_custom_bigint_hash(BIGINT, BIGINT);
```

Now you can declare partitioned table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
   id SERIAL,
   partition_id BIGINT,
   value TEXT
) PARTITION BY HASH (partition_id);

CREATE TABLE  some_table_part_2 PARTITION OF some_table FOR VALUES WITH (modulus 3, remainder 2);
```

Now you can safely assume that allow rows with `partition_id % 3 = 2` will land in `some_table_part_2` partition. So if you are sure what values you will receive in `partition_id` column you can create only required partitions.

DISCLAIMER 1: Unfortunately this will not work correctly right now (Postgres 13.1) because of [bug #16840](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/16840-571a22976f829ad4%40postgresql.org)

DISCLAIMER 2: There is not point of using this technic unless you are planning to create large number of partitions (I would say 50 or more) and prolonged planning time is an issue.

Comment: I still don't understand why you are not using the default `hashint8` function.

Comment: 1. In my case the same schema will be applied to many DB   2. In all DB I want to have at most 500 partitions      3. I don't want to create all partitions at the very beginning because planning time for 500 partitions are long -> create only those partitions that are needed.   4. I have to know to which partition given row will go so I can be sure that partition exists for that row  so I can use default hashint8 function because I will not be able to predict it's output.

Comment: Sounds more like a case for list or range partitioning.

Comment: I keep in DB information about directories from different hard drives. Each harddrive has id. Directories from each harddrive are kept together on single partition. Thre are cases when someone has <1000 hdds in that case I want to have at most 500 partitions, each keeps information about dirs from 2 hdds. List partitioning was my initial solution but it has problem of not supporting high values of hdd_id. Simple range partitioning does not distribute hdds to different partitions where there are only few hdds. I have to implement general solution that will cover all possible cases.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is the default hashint8 the one where you cannot easily anticipate to which partition a specific value will go ?  for once, I needed to be sure that id=0 goes to partition 0, id=1 goes to 1, id=2 goes to 2, id=3 to 3 and id=4 goes back to partition 0 and then in a cyclic manner. this is important because I prepare csv and inject them directly to partitions, it should be trivial to populate rows to their corresponding csvs.

Comment: @NirO. I have my doubts that that serves any good purpose, but you could use `PARTITION BY LIST (id % 3)`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  I might be missing something bcz create table testlist
(   id bigserial ) partition by LIST (id%3);  generates syntax error

Comment: @NirO. You are missing extra parentheses around the expression. Sorry.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe your solution fails if id is a primary key as opposed to the custom hash solution

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have no questions. Michał's solution works perfectly. The comments are for the sake of the readers who may walk in the 'partition by list' path wrongfully

Comment: `PARTITION BY LIST ((id % 3))` works fine, primary key or not.